# Count empty list in Prolog list of list

Tags: list, prolog

Learning Prolog still,

I made the predicate `empties(L,R)` that accepts a list of groups in L (i.e.: `[  [ 2 ] ,[ 1 ] ,[ ]  ]` ) and the `R` indicates the number of empty groups within the group, so for this particular case it should go

```
empties([[2],[1],[]],1)
```

it gives 'yes' for this particular case, which seems to make sense.

if i ask:

```
empties([[],[2],[2],[]],X).
```

it will answer `X = 2`, which again makes sense, but when i replace the `X` with a 0, it gives a yes too, and i can't get a grasp on why. It seems to be asking "at least X" and not exactly the number of occurences.

This is the code:

```
isit([]).
empties([],0).
empties([X|L] , R):-
        isit(X),
        empties(L,K),
        R is K+1.

empties([X|L] , K):-
        empties(L,K).
```

Thank you for your precious help.

Comment: Did you get this error? `Singleton variables: [X]` Also did you notice that you are hitting a choice-point? e.g. with SWI-Prolog you have to press the space bar to end the query.

Comment: I think that is a warning, not an error , but i could be wrong... What do you mean by hiting a choice-point?

Comment: A choice-point means that there is another possible result because during the running of the program a choice could be made. The program made the first choice and proceeded, since there is another choice to be made Prolog signals that to you when using top by not returning `.`. For the query `empties([[2],[1],[]],1).` I had to press the space bar or Enter to get `.`. Pressing the space bar will show you the next result and Enter will end the query, so I always press the space bar to see the next result in case there is an answer I was not expecting.

Comment: Anytime you see `Singleton variables` start looking at your code and logic very carefully. Every time I get it there is something wrong with my code, or I know exactly why I have a singleton variable, usually because I have commented out some code during testing.

Comment: The answer to `empties([[],[2],[2],[]],X).` is actually `X = 2 ; X = 1 ; X = 1 ; X = 0.` because of the choice-points. Use space bar instead of Enter to see them all.

Comment: See [this](http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse6). It talks about choice points in more detail than I can put into a comment.

Comment: @Souza yes, "Singleton variable" is a warning, but warnings are to be heeded (in any programming language)! They can be an indicator of a bug. Warning means that it is not fatal to the program, but could mean that you forgot something or did something wrong.

Comment: The problem is the rule, `empties([X|L] , K):-
        empties(L,K).` which says that `K` is the number of empty lists in `[X|L]` if `K` is the number of empty lists in `L`. This isn't true. What if `X` is empty?

Comment: @lurker in that case, X cannot be empty if it enters at "empties([X|L], K)" because it already failed in the previous entry where it tests with isit . So, not empty on that particular spot.

Comment: RIght. But that predicate clause *allows* `X` to be `[]`. So it *can* be empty, which is why `empties([[],[2],[2],[]],0).` succeeds. You need to ensure `X` is not `[]` in that clause. When you read your rule, as I did in my last comment, it needs to be logical and correct. In this case, it is not.

Comment: For your last clause, just do, `empties([[_|_]|L] , K):- 
        empties(L,K).`. That ensures that the head of the list is not the empty list. This is an important condition for this rule. Without this condition, the rule is not correct, as I described in my first comment. With the condition, it no reads that, *The number of empty list elements in `[[_|_]|L]` is `K` if the number of empty list elements in `L` is `K`*, which is always true since we've forced the head of the list in the first argument to be non-empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is a set of rules that define the number of empty list elements. Ideally, these should (a) give you all of the correct answers, (b) not give you incorrect answers, and (c) hopefully not overlap in giving you answers (provide the same answer multiple times).

You have three clauses for your `empties/2` predicate, which we'll examine.

```
empties([],0).
```

This one says

> The empty list has no empty list elements.

That is logically correct.

```
empties([X|L] , R):-
    isit(X),
    empties(L,K),
    R is K+1.
```

This can be rewritten/simplified:

```
empties([[]|L], R) :-
    empties(L, K),
    R is K + 1.
```

This says that

> The number of empty list elements in the list `[[] | L]` is `R` if the number of empty list elements in the list `L` is `K`, and `R` is `K + 1`.

That also is logically correct.

```
empties([X|L] , K):-
    empties(L,K).
```

This rule says that

> The number of empty list elements in the list `[X|L]` {no matter what `X` is!} is `K` if the number of empty list elements in the list `L` is `K`.

This is certainly **not** logically correct, and this is why your query, `empties([[],[2],[2],[]],0).` succeeds. If `X = []`, this rule still succeeds. This third clause, in conjunction with your first clause of `empties([], 0)`, will allow any query of the form `empties(L, 0)`, where `L` is a list, to succeed. In this case, you must enforce that `X` is not empty, to make the rule mean:

> The number of empty list elements in the list `[X|L]` is `K` if `X` is *not* empty, and the number of empty list elements in the list `L` is `K`.

So your third rule must ensure that `X` is not the empty list for it to be satisfied properly. This can be done this way:

```
empties([X|L] , K) :-
    X \= [],
    empties(L,K).
```

Or, you can do it more elegantly this way:

```
empties([[_|_]|L], K) :-
    empties(L, K).
```

`[_|_]` is an anonymous list of one or more elements.

Comment: Great answer @lurker, that was very instructional !

Answer (score 1):

You understand how to take a list apart:

```erlang
[X|L]
```

You understand how to use recursion:

```erlang
empties([X|L] , R):-
    ...
    empties(L,K),
```

You understand a base case with recursion:

```erlang
empties([],0).
```

You understand how to do arithmetic with Prolog:

```erlang
R is K+1
```

You are using [guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guard_(computer_science)) whether you know it or not:

```erlang
empties([],0)    % [] is the guard
```

So you have the basic mechanics necessary to solve this problem but putting the pieces together to work with Prolog eludes you for this problem.

### Solution

The key to the below solution uses two guard statements that complement each other, meaning only one or the other can be chosen. Think of them like an `if` statement in that they choose one or the other predicates. Once you understand how the guards work in Prolog don't think of them as `if` statements when doing Prolog because you will then start to think procedurally instead of logically which will not be good; they are capable of so much more.

```erlang
H == []
H \= []
```

Also it threads the count variable `R` through the predicates.

```erlang
empties([], R, R).

empties([H|T], R0, R) :-
    H == [],
    R1 is R0 + 1,
    empties(T, R1, R).

empties([H|T], R0, R) :-
    H \= [],
    empties(T, R0, R).

empties(L,R) :-
    empties(L,0,R).
```

### Output

```erlang
?- empties([],X).
X = 0.

?- empties([[]],X).
X = 1 ;
false.

?- empties([[],[a]],X).
X = 1 ;
false.

?- empties([[a],[]],X).
X = 1 ;
false.

?- empties([[],[]],X).
X = 2 ;
false.

?- empties([[a],[],[b]],X).
X = 1 ;
false.

?- empties([[],[a],[b]],X).
X = 1 ;
false.

?- empties([[a],[b],[]],X).
X = 1 ;
false.

?- empties([[],[],[]],X).
X = 3 ;
false.
```

Comment: Thank you so very much for the great answer @Guy Coder, wish i could select more than one correct answer my friend!

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach using `findall/3` predicate:

```
empties(L,N):-findall(X, (member(X,L),X = []) ,L1),length(L1,N).
```

What te above solution does is that it finds all X, which are member of L and are empty lists and adds it to L1, then it returns the length of L1.

Examples:

```
?- empties([[],[2],[2],[]],X).
X = 2.

?- empties([],X).
X = 0.

?- empties([[]],X).
X = 1.

?- empties([[],[_]],X).
X = 1.

?- empties([[],[2],[2],[]],2).
true.
```